# identify textfield value to hide the DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, textfield

i have a textfield:

```
<input type="text" id="modname" />
```

and a div:

```
 <div id="tuner">
         <tr>        
         <td width="400">
            Tuner
            <div id="value" name="tuner"></div>
         </td>
         <td width="10">:</td>
         <td width="150">
            <input id="tuner_rng1" type="radio" class="tuner_rng" name="tuner_rng" value="OK" />OK
            <input id="tuner_rng2" type="radio" class="tuner_rng" name="tuner_rng" value="NG" />NG
            <label for="tuner_rng" class="error">Please choose one !</label>
         </td>
         </tr>
 </div>
```

i want if textfield value have "CH" character in front of text the div will hide.for example: if i type "change","check" it will hidden. How do i do that? could jquery do like that without regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
$('#modname').keyup(function() {
   if($(this).val().toLowerCase().substring(0,2) == 'ch') {
      $('#value').hide();   
   } else {
      $('#value').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: how about showing the div back when user deletes the starting `ch`. :)

Comment: Damn, there are always someone faster than me :)

Comment: @Klaster_t Your solution is perfectly fine as well. :)

Comment: @all: i have change the div, so i try this answer but its not working.

Comment: @klox: both answers work fine for me. Is it possible that you've mistyped the id?

Comment: @jacob: i try to make a div round of <tr>. after i type CH the div still show.

Comment: @klox: Change it to '#value' and you should be all set.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code:

```
$('#modname').bind('keyup',function(){
    (/\bch/i.test($(this).val()))?$('#value').hide():$('#value').show();
});
```

Comment: @`Damn, there are always someone faster than me`, o yes cos regex is always slower than simple manipulation. ;P